# Update statement in JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: sql, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am not able to update the database table correctly using JdbcBatchItemWriter. Below is the code fragment. insert on an empty table is getting correct response but update is not happening on input table.

```
<bean id="odbWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                update employeethree set salary = :salary, designation = :designation, promotioneligibility = :promotionEligibility 
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
    <bean
    class="batchjobreaddb.CustomBeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
```

If i change the query inside CDATA to :

```
insert into employeetwo values(:empId, :empName, :dept , :salary, :designation, :experienceInMonths, :promotionEligibility)
```

then it's getting me the desired results. (EmployeeTwo has same structure but is empty.)

Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide the code of your custom parameterSourceProvider. Furthermore, what do you mean by  "i am not able"; is there an exception, or are the wrong data inserted, or ... ?

Comment: Is there a commit somewhere ?

Comment: Below mention answer is correct. WHERE clause should be present if you trying to update the item thats being read from ItemReader.

Answer (score 2):

Your [`UPDATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) query has no [`WHERE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause.  How are you to know which record to update?

For proper update behavior, you must specify a `WHERE` clause that properly identifies the record(s) you wish to modify with the `UPDATE` query.

This is obviously not necessary with an [`INSERT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) query, because you are creating a brand new record and not modifying an existing one.

Assuming from your example `INSERT` query that the employee id field is `empid`, try modifying your [`JdbcBatchItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html) to set the `sql` value to:

```xml
<property name="sql">
    <value>
        <![CDATA[
            UPDATE employeethree 
            SET salary = :salary, 
                designation = :designation, 
                promotioneligibility = :promotionEligibility 
            WHERE empid = :empId
         ]]>
    </value>
</property>
```